# equivalence of eslint rule import/named in commonjs

Tags: eslint

EsLint has one rule `import/named` which can be used to check if the imported names exist in the export files. but this rule does not work in Commonjs , is there any rule equivalence in Commonjs?

Comment: found a solution or workaround for this?